# What is the rank of a tensor bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tensors, vector-bundles

If M is a differentiable manifold of dimension n, then what is  the rank of the vector bundle $\mathcal{T}^l_m(M)$?
Thank you.

Comment: It would be better if you defined the notation $\mathcal{T}^l_m(M)$. Is it the bundle of $(l,m)$-tensors on $M$?

Comment: Yes, it is. @Steve

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is $n^{l+m}$, since the tensor space $T^l_m$ has dimension $n^{l+m}$.

Comment: Is it the case that $T_m^l$ is the fibre of $\mathcal{T}^l_m(M)$? In this case the answer is yes (by definition).

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you.